# Any way to debug javascript on Android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, debugging

Are there any means of debugging JS code, or at least get errors, on Android devices?

Answer (score 2):

This helps:

http://www.nanaze.com/2009/01/debugging-javascript-on-android.html

There are Firebug like methods (e.g. console.debug, console.info) that will log to logcat, so you can snoop there.

In my testing I'm getting logs to `W/browser`, not `D/WebCore`, but the info is being logged there.

Answer (score 0):

Error messages should show up in the log with the [WebCore](http://www.nanaze.com/2009/01/debugging-javascript-on-android.html) tag.

Answered [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468993/is-there-a-way-to-enable-the-javascript-error-debug-console-for-safari-within-and#487622).

Comment: We answered with the same link at the same time. See my answer - it looks like the Tag isn't always WebCore - perhaps it is if the browser view is embedded in an app.

Answer (score 0):

As it says http://www.technomancy.org/android/javascript-debugging/ you use can use `console.log(...)` to log messages, and then install a log viewer to view the logs if you filter based on `browser` (at least on Android 2.2)