# A web app using kendoui doesn't run on android tablet

Tags: android, web-applications, kendo-ui

I developed a  web application that turns in different browser(opera,firefox,chrome).when i access via tablets except the native browser of android.i tried with different tablets and the same problem.It ignores the composant such as datepicker...I didn't find a tool to debug the site.i tested it with android 2.3

I'm waiting your reply.that's very important to help me.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Kendo Web or Kendo Mobile? Can you show the HTML that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get more insights why it is not working if you see the javascript console and its output. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468993/is-there-a-way-to-enable-the-javascript-error-debug-console-for-safari-within-an) will tell you how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI Mobile only provides styling for the native browser input, select and textarea elements. This means that you won't get date/time pickers where they are not supported. Default Android browser doesn't support HTML5 input pickers, thus you won't get any. You can work around that by using some kind of validation there or use a third party library as MobiScroll.

Also note that Firefox and Opera are not officially supported.