# .load() Function on Android Applikation with webview

Tags: android, jquery, webview

I want to creat an Android Application with HTML, CSS, and jQuery.
I have tried to implement the `.load()` function of jQuery on this way. It works on the browser but not as an Android Application. Is there an other solution, for example with AJAX?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    function loadContent() {
      $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
      $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

  });
});
```

Thanks

**Edit:**

i tried also this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
// handle menu clicks
$("ul#nav li a").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#content").load(page + ".html");

});
```

});

Comment: Are you just using the Android browser to view this or are you embedding some kind of webview?

Comment: Its a webview with eclpise as IDE

Comment: Check out this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html#WebView which should show you console messages in the case of JavaScript errors within your WebView. It helps debugging JS inside WebView cases.

Comment: Also this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468993/is-there-a-way-to-enable-the-javascript-error-debug-console-for-safari-within-an

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that there is a error in the JS. I tried different ways and solutions which I found on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution: 
function getContent(href) {

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        //url: href + ".html",
        //url : "http://localhost/ProVid/" + href + ".html",
        url: "http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~lieneman/pages/" + href + ".html",
        //url: "http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~lieneman/pages/vorstellung.html",
        dataType : "html",


        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        },
        success : parseHTML,

        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);


            $('#content').html("<h3 style='text-align: center;'>Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten</h3>");

        }
    });

}
```

But you have also to know that this is only working on a webspace or virtual webspace like xampp and you have to at "#" to the href attribute.